# Compiling opencl app first time

Tags: compiling, opengl

I have some simple opencl source code for compilation. Every time when I tried to do this: `g++ test.cpp -lglut -lGLU -lGL`. Is there a way to avoid typing the last 3 things?

Comment: ... write a [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a minimal [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)

Ex.

```
$ cat Makefile

CXX := g++
LIBS := -lglut -lGLU -lGL

test:   test.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

You can then compile and link `test` simply using

```
make test
```

or even, since `test` is the default (first) target

```
make
```